# pcre regex for removing adjacent duplicates

Tags: regex, pcre

Given a string having duplicate characters, what would be the proper regex to remove adjacent duplicates?
I am unable to figure out how to use backreference to write final output.
For eg.
input: "1111112222223333344444111";
output: "12341"

Comment: Put what you have been trying so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this:

```
pattern: (.)\g{1}+
replacement: $1
```

or this:

```
pattern: (.)\K\g{1}+
```

and nothing for replacement

example with php:

```
preg_replace('~(.)\K\g{1}+~', '', '1111112222223333344444111');
```